# how to generate this json in java?

Tags: json, gson

```
"agencies": {
    "1": {
        assignedAgencies: [
            "agency1",
            "agency2",
            "agency5"],
        restOfAgencies: [
            "agency3",
            "agency4",
            "agency6"],
        global: "true"
    },
        "2": {
        assignedAgencies: [
            "agency6",
            "agency5"],
        restOfAgencies: [
            "agency1",
            "agency2",
            "agency3",
            "agency4"],
         global: "false"
    }

}
```

I would like to create a function that return a json :

```
generateJson (List assignedAgenciesList, List restOfAgenciesList,String global) { ...}
```

to genare the above json.

Comment: Asking others to write code for you is not in the spirit of this site.

Comment: I am not asking others to write code for me, I am asking this because the structure of the above json has arrays.

Comment: You appear to ask permission: "I would like to create a function that ...", nothing more. You do not mention any problem or question. Well, okay ... go ahead! (But in case there is a question hidden in here after all: please read the guidelines in [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use an API for JSON processing... [This one](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html) for exemple.

Answer (score 0):

For you to generate the JSON using GSON you need to have the appropriate data structures that just "magically" correspond to your JSON

Have a look at for example [www.jsonschema2pojo.org](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org) which can generate the necessary Java objects given the JSON output.

But you need to look closer as to how your schema is defined. For simple mappings having a field named "1" for example is not allowed in Java, so you need to either use extra annotations that always map any field name to this number, or define a map serializer.

On a closer inspection, it looks like you are enumerating, so maybe all you want is an array `[]` of agency elements?

If you want to just write JSON have a look at the `JsonWriter` class ([Javadoc](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/stream/JsonWriter.html))

Comment: Have you looked at the Gson user guide?https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Array-Examples It has examples for arrays and the like

Comment: Thank you Joey for your help, but I can't do it, I wish I will find a tutorial example somewhere, I am mostly a front end developer.